# Smooth scroll to div not working?

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I am working on a sticky navigation where a user would click on navigation link to scroll to that particular section.

**jquery for script:**

```
$('navbar-brand, .action-button, .navHeaderCollapse a[href^="#"]').on('click', function(event) {
    var target = $(this.href);
    if( target.length ) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 2000);
    }
});
```

Clicking on link does take it to that section but it is immediate i.e. without any delay or not smooth.

Comment: Can you give us a fiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following code, `this.href` will gives you full url. so try to get teh attribute instead of that

```
$('navbar-brand, .action-button, .navHeaderCollapse a[href^="#"]').on('click', function (event) {
    var target = $($(this).attr("href")); <-- this line will do the trick
    if (target.length) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 2000);
    }
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kwa6dtrz/)

Answer (score -1):

See http://jsfiddle.net/uehcpcg5/

You had a mistype with

```
var target = $(this.href);
```

should be

```
var target = $(this).href
```

which returns undefined anyway.

Changed that to

```
$(this).prop("href");
```

which returns the full url, so split it with # to get the id of the target div, then scrolled to that. SO looks like your event wasn't processing href correctly.